# グラフが重なって表示されてしまうのやめたい

Tags: python

現在pythonを用いて何秒かごとの測定を行おうと考えており、グラフを作るため、pythonのmatplotlibを使追うと考えています。
しかし、下記のようなコードを書くと、ループされたあと、グラフの中に前回読み込んだテキストまで読み込まれてしまい本来表示させたいものとかぶって表示されてしまいます。

どうすれば前のテキストデータを消去し、最新のテキストのデータのみを読み込ませることができるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import datetime
import time
import os

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

os.mkdir("test")

oclock = datetime.datetime.today()

while True:

    data = np.loadtxt('exp-data.txt',delimiter=' ',unpack=True)

    xm = data[:,0]
    ym = data[:,1]

    x = xm/1023
    y = ym/1023

    plt.plot(x,y)

    os.chdir("/home/ienaga/デスクトップ/matplot_test/test")
    plt.savefig('sample.png')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    newname = "{0:%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S}.png".format(now)
    a = os.rename("sample.png",newname)
    os.chdir("/home/ienaga/デスクトップ/matplot_test")

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.loadtext()` の前の行で `plt.figure()` を呼んでみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 'plt.figure()' を入れることで一旦リセットされうまく描きたいグラフが描かれるようになりました。  [plt.figure()]で新規ウィンドウ描写とは初めて知りました！　本当にありがとうございました！